# Transferring data from Windows to Ubuntu is way slow

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, scp

I'm trying to upload a 6GB file from Windows to a (remote) Linux machine.

Results:

- over both SFTP and SCP (WinSCP): tx speed is **90-100kbps**.
- over plain insecure FTP (FileZilla): tx speed is **80-100kbps**.

Environment:

- Windows10 (sender) runs on Intel i7 processor and 16GB RAM.
- Linux Ubuntu (receiver) runs likewise on Intel i7 and 32GB RAM.
- Both machines are using SSD storages.
- Both machines are wired to their routers (no Wifi involved - at least locally).
- ISP limits (uplink/downlink) are pretty far from this limitation, measured in many * 10Mbps if not 100Mbps in both directions, in both places.

Proof that problem is in the Windows machine:

In case I'm transferring the same file from a Raspberry Pi1 (Arm, single core @700Mhz), transfer speed reaches ~20MBps (with standard scp command). In this test-case the Pi is in the same LAN as the original Windows10 sender machine. (Receiver is intact during this testcase!)

[image]

What could I check on the Windows10 machine to resolve this issue? I don't like to copy all files to an SD card first, then putting the card to the Pi1, to be able to upload the files to Linux.

Measuring speedtest on Windows10:

[image]

Comment: Look at the loading on each router at both ends. I would first suspect people viewing videos.

Comment: Both are in between 0-2%.

Comment: *n this test-case the Pi is in the same LAN as the original Windows10 sender* So this is a completely useless test.

Comment: Because you'd likely find similar if not better results if the machines in your question were also in the same LAN. Nothing useful can be inferred form testing network speed locally that can have any significance when troubleshooting the speed of remote connections. It should be obvious.

Comment: Can you try a Windows machine at the remote end with the same network setup as the Ubuntu machine to see if network is the culprit

Comment: @John: that's not possible unfortunately.

Comment: What does the data have to traverse to get to the Linux machine? You have compared to a same-LAN Pi without telling us what the problem network is.

Comment: My bad. I must've misread that paragraph. I wasn't the only one though ^

Comment: If you use an internet speed tester on the Windows machine (e.g. Speedtest from the Microsoft Store), what upload speed does it indicate?

Comment: (1) What is the network adapter on Windows 10 and are you using the latest driver? (2) Try to disable Auto-Tuning: `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`, (3) In "Turn Windows features on or off", check that "Remote Differential Compression API Support" is unchecked.

Comment: (1): USB (typeC) Realtek GbE Faimily Controller, and Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A WLAN (tried on both, same results). Both are having the latest driver, yes. (2) and (3): OK, I changed, rebooted. Still Filezilla @80kbps sending.

Comment: You could try booting a Linux Live USB and test if you get the same transfer speeds. If Linux does better, then the problem is with Windows. If it does the same, the problem is probably with the computer.

Comment: Could you please test `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0` on the server side?

Comment: One more question: Is this your [Realtek driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)?

Comment: @harrymc: no, I believe no, as this is for PCI, and mine is USB. Chip ID is RTL8153. However, it's not related to it, as exactly same speeds are reached on Wifi (5GHz). Live USB is brilliant idea! I'll do that.

Comment: @user1686: do I need to reboot after setting this? If not, then sorry, doesn't solve. Same 80-100kbps.